# Using JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean, or an equivalent, in Spring Boot 3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, jax-ws

I'm trying to upgrade a project that makes use of `org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean` in Spring Boot 2.7.5 to Spring Boot 3. Here's the declaration of my bean:

```java
@Bean
public JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean myJaxWsClient() {
    JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean = new JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean();
    jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setJaxWsService(new My_Service());
    jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setWsdlDocumentUrl(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/my.wsdl"));
    jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setNamespaceUri("urn:net:something");
    jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setServiceName("MyService");
    jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setServiceInterface(My.class);
    jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setEndpointAddress("http://someuri:7979/myservice");
    jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setUsername("username");
    jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setPassword("password");
    return jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean;
}
```

However, `org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean` doesn't seem to be available in Spring Boot 3, or it has moved to another library.

My question is: How do I use `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean` in Spring Boot 3, or how do I migrate to a more modern alternative (if available)?

Comment: You don't as it has been removed inline with the other older remoting technologies. You probably need to switch to another way of registering/creating those proxies, like Apache CXF or write an implementation with Spring Web Services.

Comment: Maybe this should be an answer?

Comment: I was gathering some additional resources (like the ticket and commit) to reference to. But an answer has been written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This class, as many others, has been removed in Spring Framework 6 (which is used by Spring Boot 3). It has been documented by [this Github ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27422) and this [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/5822f1bf85b94fd15f9829914b065b1c61910c7d). The old style remoting support (due to vulnerabilities and better options available) has been removed from the core library.

For the JAX-WS part you probably want to use something like [Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org) in the current day and age, which would allow for a dynamic proxy. Another option is to implement the client yourself using [Spring Web Services](https://spring.io/projects/spring-ws)

Answer (score 1):

Jakarta JAXWS-RI is also an option: You generate MyService and MyPort using the jaxws-maven-plugin. Then you set it up using Spring, assuming you have written a MyConfigProperties class to access application.properties.

In a MyConfig class which sets up the beans and takes the MyConfigProperties, also adding SSL support for good measure:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

  public MyConfig(MyConfigProperties myConfigProperties) {
    this.myConfigProperties = myConfigProperties;
  }

  @Bean
  public MyService myService() {
    try {
        URL wsdlLocation = this.getClass().getResource("/META-INF/wsdl/my.wsdl");
        return new MyService(wsdlLocation); // may pass features here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw(new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
  }

  @Bean
  public KeyStoreFactoryBean keyStore() {
      KeyStoreFactoryBean keyStoreFactoryBean = new KeyStoreFactoryBean();
      Resource location = new ClassPathResource(myConfigProperties.getKeystoreLocation());
      keyStoreFactoryBean.setLocation(location);
      keyStoreFactoryBean.setPassword(myConfigProperties.getKeystorePassword());
      return keyStoreFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public KeyStoreFactoryBean trustStore() {
      KeyStoreFactoryBean keyStoreFactoryBean = new KeyStoreFactoryBean();
      Resource location = new ClassPathResource(myConfigProperties.getTruststoreLocation());
      keyStoreFactoryBean.setLocation(location);
      keyStoreFactoryBean.setPassword(myConfigProperties.getTruststorePassword());
      return keyStoreFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public TrustManagersFactoryBean trustManagers(KeyStore trustStore) {
      TrustManagersFactoryBean trustManagersFactoryBean = new TrustManagersFactoryBean();
      trustManagersFactoryBean.setKeyStore(trustStore);
      return trustManagersFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public KeyManagersFactoryBean keyManagers(KeyStore keyStore) {
      KeyManagersFactoryBean keyManagersFactoryBean = new KeyManagersFactoryBean();
      keyManagersFactoryBean.setKeyStore(keyStore);
      keyManagersFactoryBean.setPassword(props.getKeystorePassword());
      return keyManagersFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory(TrustManager[] trustManagers, KeyManager[] keyManagers) throws Exception {
      SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
      sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
      return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
  }
}
```

In your client implementation:

```
@Component
public class MyClient {

  public MyClient(MyService myService, MyConfigProperties props,
      SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory) {
    this.myPort = myService.getMyPort();
    this.props = props;
    this.sslSocketFactory = sslSocketFactory;
  }

  public MyResult callEndpoint() {    
    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) msgBoxPort;
    Map<String, Object> requestContext = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();
    requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, props.getWebserviceUri());
    requestContext.put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslSocketFactory);
    return myPort.callEndpoint();
  }
}
```

For the code generation you might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77465064/743507, I just recently went through the hassle to build a SOAP client for a rather complex WSDL, where I had to download a lot of schema files and needed a catalog to point the jaxws-maven-plugin to the downloaded stuff. This is generally a good idea, because you don't want your client to fail during startup if the target service is not available (or doesn't publish its WSDL properly).

Comment: Also note that the JAXWSProperties class is in different packages, depending on the JAXWS implementation.
JAXWS-RI: com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, Oracle JDK 8: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, some WebLogic versions: weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY