# wsimport - 'XXX' is already defined, the first definition appears here

Tags: jaxb, wsimport, jaxws-maven-plugin, xta, osci

I am generating Java classes using a [WSDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) file that imports and includes a whole slew of other schemas and [DTDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition), which in turn reference each other. (It is the infamous 'standard' [XTA2 V3](https://www.xrepository.de/details/urn:xoev-de:kosit:standard:xta2) WSDL file, to name names. Standard in quotes because one would assume that a standard WSDL file can be generated with standard tools without requiring patches.)

The error messages I get look like this:

```
[ERROR] 'NonEmptyStringType' is already defined
  Zeile 17 von file:/C:/Users/itbc000257/Documents/projekte/km-tafe/src/main/resources/META-INF/wsdl/OSCI_MessageMetaData_V2.02.xsd
[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  Zeile 12 von file:/C:/Users/itbc000257/Documents/projekte/km-tafe/src/main/resources/META-INF/wsdl/OSCI_MessageMetaData_V2.02.xsd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by schema imports where one schema referenced the `schemaLocation` with a relative path, whereas the others use an absolute http URL.

*OSCI2_02.xsd* uses a relative `schemaLocation`:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.osci.eu/ws/2014/10/transport"
  schemaLocation="OSCI_MessageMetaData_V2.02.xsd"/>
```

XTA.wsdl, XTA-synchron.wsdl, XTA-Webservice-Datentypen.xsd, XTA-Webservice-Globale-Elemente.xsd use an absolute `schemaLocation` URL:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.osci.eu/ws/2014/10/transport"
  schemaLocation="http://www.osci.eu/ws/2014/10/transport/OSCI_MessageMetaData_V2.02.xsd"/>
```

There is a long-standing [bug in xjc from the jaxb-ri](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/1045) which mishandles this problem, and a proposed fix by the late [Highsource](https://github.com/highsource), which never made it into the product.

In my case, the workaround was to download all related schemas, patch the *OSCI2_02.xsd* schema import to use the absolute URL and create a *jax-ws-catalog.xml*, so that wsimport uses my patched schema rather than downloading the broken file from the Internet.

Find my setup below.

WSDL recursive download for schema files:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Anthony/Rabiaza
# 2018-02-31
# https://github.com/anthonyrabiaza/recursiveDownloader
# Patch by dschulten: load from absolute URLs and do not download already existing files to avoid endless loops

#wget parameters:
# -T 60: timeout of 60 sec
# -nv: non verbose
# -nc: skip downloads that would download to existing files
# --secure-protocol=TLSv1 --no-check-certificate: security related
wget_params="-T 60 -nv -nc --secure-protocol=TLSv1 --no-check-certificate


function help() {
    echo "Please run this utility with the URL of the WSDL/XSD as argument"
    echo -e "\tFor instance:"
    echo -e "\t$0 http://192.168.0.96:8080/HelloWorld_WebServiceProject/wsdl/HelloWorld.wsdl"
}

function download() {
    export filename=${1##*/}
    if [ "$filename" == "" ];
    then
        echo -e "\tError for $1"
        echo -ne "\t\t"
        return -1
    fi
    echo -e "\tDownloading $filename"
    echo -en "\t\twget -> "
    wget $wget_params $1
    echo ""
}

function getDependencies() {
    export nbOccurrences=`grep -Po 'schemaLocation' $1 | wc -l`

    echo "Grepped $nbOccurrences in $1"

    if [ $nbOccurrences -gt 0 ];
        then
            export dependencies=`grep -Po 'schemaLocation="\K.*?(?=")' $1`
            echo "$dependencies" | while read -r dependency
            do
                if [ ! -f ${dependency##*/} ] ; then
                    download $dependency
                    echo Filename: ${dependency##*/}
                    getDependencies ${dependency##*/}
                fi
            done
        else
            echo -e "\t\tNo more dependencies for $1"
    fi

}

if [ $# -lt 1 ];
    then help
    exit -1
fi

currentDir="$PWD"

echo "Recursive Downloader"
echo "Command:    $0"
echo "Parameters: $*"
echo ""
echo "Creating output folder"

mkdir -p output
cd output

export filename=${1##*/}
export serverPath=${1%/*}

echo "File to download $filename on $serverPath"

download $1

getDependencies $filename $serverPath

cd "$currentDir"
```

The script doesn't download DTDs, so I also had to download:

- https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd
- https://www.w3.org/2001/datatypes.dtd

All downloaded files go into *src/main/resources/META-INF/wsdl*.

The following *jax-ws-catalog.xml* file in the same folder tells wsimport to look for the downloaded files rather than downloading them from the Internet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog" prefer="system">
    <system systemId="http://www.osci.eu/ws/2014/10/transport/OSCI_MessageMetaData_V2.02.xsd"
            uri="OSCI_MessageMetaData_V2.02.xsd"/>
    <system systemId="http://www.w3.org/2006/03/addressing/ws-addr.xsd" uri="ws-addr.xsd"/>
    <system systemId="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
            uri="oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"/>
    <system systemId="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
            uri="oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"/>
    <system systemId="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd" uri="xml.xsd"/>
    <system systemId="http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" uri="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
    <system systemId="http://xoev.de/schemata/basisdatentypen/1_1/xoev-basisdatentypen.xsd"
            uri="xoev-basisdatentypen.xsd"/>
    <system systemId="http://www.osci.eu/ws/2014/10/transport/OSCI2_02.xsd" uri="OSCI2_02.xsd"/>
    <system systemId="http://www.w3.org/2007/02/ws-policy.xsd" uri="ws-policy.xsd"/>
    <system systemId="http://xoev.de/transport/xta/211/XTA-Webservice-Globale-Elemente.xsd"
            uri="XTA-Webservice-Globale-Elemente.xsd"/>
    <system systemId="http://xoev.de/transport/xta/211/xenc-schema.xsd" uri="xenc-schema.xsd"/>
    <system systemId="http://xoev.de/transport/xta/211/XTA-Webservice-Exceptions.xsd"
            uri="XTA-Webservice-Exceptions.xsd"/>
    <system systemId="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" uri="soap-envelope.xsd"/>
    <system systemId="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd" uri="XMLSchema.dtd"/>
</catalog>
```

Here my jaxws-maven-plugin definition which uses the [jakarta-ee edition of the plugin](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/metro-jax-ws/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html) (suitable above Java 8), together with the [patrodyne hisrc-basicjaxb-plugins](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme) for jakarta-ee XML for generation of toString, etc.:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/META-INF/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
        <wsdlFiles>
            <wsdlFile>XTA.wsdl</wsdlFile>
        </wsdlFiles>
        <wsdlLocation>/META-INF/wsdl/XTA.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
        <vmArgs>
            <!-- Needed for file access to datatypes.dtd in the local file system -->
            <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all</vmArg>
        </vmArgs>
        <args>-XadditionalHeaders</args>
        <catalog>src/main/resources/META-INF/wsdl/jax-ws-catalog.xml</catalog>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <xjcArgs>
            <xjcArg>-XfluentAPI</xjcArg>
            <xjcArg>-XsimpleToString</xjcArg>
            <xjcArg>-XsimpleEquals</xjcArg>
            <xjcArg>-XsimpleHashCode</xjcArg>
        </xjcArgs>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.patrodyne.jvnet</groupId>
            <artifactId>hisrc-basicjaxb-plugins</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

And finally, the generated classes need *jakarta.xml* dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <jakarta.xml.version>4.0.1</jakarta.xml.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jakarta.xml.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Sidenote: The XTA2 V3 page has a cxf based example Xta Client. https://www.xoev.de/osci-xta/xta/hilfsmittel-23081, in case you are looking for XTA example code.